# Including javafx.util.Pair as a dependency in gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, javafx, dependencies

I have a springboot app that I developed using oracle JDK and it uses the javafx.util.pair class. When the jar built is run on a system with OpenJDK it cannot find this class. How can i package this dependency with my jar? I am using gradle. Here is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE")
    }
}

description = "CF Service Broker using Java / Spring"

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'cf-tile'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: Is it worth bringing all of JavaFX into your project just for that one class?  A class which is not only trivial to implement from scratch, but which, for almost all use cases, should be a meaningful class that describes what its two values actually represent?

Comment: @vgr I agree. I have already done what you suggested. But just for academic purposes, I wish to know if it is is possible(especially just including that class and its dependencies... not the entire JavaFX package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can import javafx utils via gradle but you can, for platforms that do not include it in their version of OpenJDK, use openjfx.

For example you can install it in ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```